# Outlook Recipient address in to field

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm creating a custom reply were the outlook send from account is changed and some field are automatically filled.

First I'll explain how it works we receive an e-mail. The e-mail address that receives this e-mail is in the CC. I created a button in the top-bar. When i press this button a new e-mail screen opens with some information already filled in and the remaining information we will need to fill in our self.

For the most I have everything setup. But one thing I can't get to work. I want the new e-mail to be send to the original TO (recipient) Address.

For now i have this code:

```
Sub ReplyUsingAccount()
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strAcc As String
Dim i As Long
Set objItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
strAcc = "myemail@email.nl"
For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
    If oAccount.DisplayName = strAcc Then
        Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With oMail
            .SendUsingAccount = oAccount
            .To = objItem.RecipientEmailAddress
            .Subject = "Aangaande uw bestelling bij "
                       .HTMLBody = "<br><br><br>" & _
                        "<hr width=""50%"" size=""2"" noshade />" & _
                        "<font color=""#6699ff"">" & _
                        objItem.HTMLBody & "</font>"
            .Display
        End With
    End If
Next oAccount
Set oAccount = Nothing
Set objItem = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

The **`.To = objItem.RecipientEmailAddress`** won't work.
Anyone got a solution for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's not returning the `SMTP` e-mail address as you're using returning the `.SenderEmailAddress` property on an internal e-mail address (which means it will be `EX` type address, instead of `SMTP`).

The below will return the `SMTP` address for both internal and external.

```
Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim senderAddress As String, recipEntryId As String, SmtpMailAddress As String
Dim oAddressEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry, oExchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim oReply As Outlook.MailItem, oRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem

If objItem.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then

    senderAddress = objItem.SenderEmailAddress

Else

    Set oReply = objItem.Reply()
    Set oRecipient = oReply.Recipients.Item(1)

    recipEntryId = oRecipient.EntryID

    oReply.Close OlInspectorClose.olDiscard

    recipEntryId = oRecipient.EntryID

    Set oAddressEntry = oOutlook.GetAddressEntryFromID(recipEntryId)
    Set oExchangeUser = oAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()

    senderAddress = oExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()

End If

SmtpMailAddress = senderAddress
```

You can then use the `getSmtpMailAddress` variable as the `.To` e-mail address.

If you're using Outlook 2010 or later, there's a way of using the [`.PropertyAccessor` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868823.aspx). I've never used this, but it could be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think `RecipientEmailAddress` is valid in VBA.

Try **`SenderEmailAddress.`**

Answer (score 0):

To move all the recipient address to **`.To`** field an example would be.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Example()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
    Dim Recipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim olRecip As String

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Item was Selected "
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Set olReply = olItem.Reply

        For Each Recipient In olItem.Recipients
            olRecip = Recipient.address & ";" & olRecip
        Next Recipient

        With olReply
            .To = olRecip ' all the Recipient
            .Subject = "Aangaande uw bestelling bij "
                       .HTMLBody = "<br><br><br>" & _
                        "<hr width=""50%"" size=""2"" noshade />" & _
                        "<font color=""#6699ff"">" & _
                        olReply.HTMLBody & "</font>"
            .Display
        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

To add Sender address **`.To = olRecip & ";" & olItem.SenderEmailAddress`**